# How can I test if a URL is a valid image with timeout on image request with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have this javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $("<img>", {
        src: "http://urlpath/img.png",
        error: function() { alert("error!"); },
        load: function() { alert("ok"); }
    });
});
```

It code works, but I need set a timeout for this request to avoid have a slow request.

Any advice will be use full to me!

Thanks:D

Comment: You also need to make it work with cached images, which means pulling `src` out of that object and instead setting it after.

Comment: Take a look at [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout). It returns an ID you can use to then cancel the timeout.

Comment: Why was this question down voted? Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
```

[READ] http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can specify the timeout as a property.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    timedout = false;
    var i = $("<img>", {
        src: "http://urlpath/img.png",
        error: function() { if (!timedout) { timedout = true; alert("error!"); } },
        load: function() { timedout = true; alert("ok"); }
    });
    window.setTimeout(function () { i.trigger('error'); i.remove(); }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried this but When the request pass the time out, execute the error function but the image request is still in proccess, do you know how to stop the image request if the time pass the 2 seconeds? Thanks

Comment: I have tried this but It isn't work the page is still requesting the image :-/

Comment: btw: it is nice to notice that [you should never set the `src` attribute to "" (empty string)](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/) because it will make a request to path of the current document (according to the standard URI resolution algorithm, this is the expected behavior and not a bug)

Comment: A `window.stop()` will probably work, but it will stop **all** the requests currently running.

Comment: Sadly there is no ".stop();" method for individual images.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var timed = false;
    var imgTO = setTimeout(function () {
        timed = true;
        alert("timed out");
    }, 2000);  // 2 second timeout
    $("<img>").on({
        error: function() {
            clearTimeout(imgTO);
            if (!timed) alert("error!");
        },
        load: function() {
            clearTimeout(imgTO);
            if (!timed) alert("ok");
        }
    }).attr("src", "http://urlpath/img.png");
});
```

Comment: @DiegoNunes I see...you meant that I left out a `)`?